# Problems with USB device and swap conf "Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb1:unknown filesystem type 'swap'"

Tags: partitioning, usb, swap

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and I read [a guide](https://www.taringa.net/+linux/readyboost-en-gnu-linux_12ottq) on how to use a USB in Linux with ReadyBoost the same way you can use it in Windows.

So I ran the following commands:

```
# mkswap /dev/sdb1
# swapon -p 32767 /dev/sdb1
```

So far so good. The problem started when I decided to use my memory again. I did everything I found, but I still have the same recurring error (see image below).

[image: Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb1:unknown filesystem type 'swap' <udisks-error-quark,0>]

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The command `swapoff` disables swap areas (devices and files); use it with `sudo` (i.e. `sudo swapoff`).

See how `/etc/fstab` is configured before and after executing the command.

On a normal PC, without swap, it looks like this:

```
/swapfile                        none            swap    sw              0       0
```